# How to memory map a hashmap to a file

Tags: java, memory, dictionary, hashmap

How to memory map a hashmap to a file in JAVA.

```
 HashMap<Long, ArrayList<String>> myMap = new HashMap<Long, ArrayList<String>>();
```

I want to memory map it to a file so that if there is any exception during the get() method of   myMap, I can retrieve the data again.

Thanks

Comment: What kind of exception occurs during the get() method?

Comment: _memory map a hashmap to a file in JAVA._ Do you mean serialization?

Comment: NO.. when you write to hashmap, it writes to the file as well. If you take data back from hashmap, it will delete from the file as well..  I want if the application stops, it can start again with previous data which was still left in the hashmap

Answer (score 2):

You should not need to back up the data in this case - if an exception is thrown during a call to `get` the data in the map should be preserved.

If the issue is that your program is crashing when an exception is thrown (which causes you to lose the data) then you should look to catch and handle the exception instead.

Comment: Not only this... Also I want if the application stops, it can start again with previous data which was still left in the hashmap